# Java 2D MultiJPanel Graphic

Tags: java, swing, graphics

`J2D.java`:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class J2D extends JFrame {
    int x, y = 0;

    public J2D() {
        setTitle("2D");
        setSize(613, 253);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
            add(new panel ());
            add(new panel2());
            Thread th = new Thread(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    while(true){
                        x++;y++;
                        repaint();
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(50);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            th.start();
    }


    private class panel extends JPanel{
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            //super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
            g2d.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
            g2d.drawString("Fear", x, y);

        }
    }

    private class panel2 extends JPanel{
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            //super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            g2d.drawString("Fear2", x + 15, y);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this code, it shows only the `Fear2` label. I need 2 classes and want to add two classes but how would it work correctly? Should I write `paint()` and `paintComponent()` methods?

Comment: Instead of sitting waiting demanding that people answer your question I suggest you spend your time reading the [Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) to understand the basics of how Swing works. You might want to start on the section dealing with layout managers. Your problem is that you are trying to add 2 components to the CENTER of a BorderLayout. If you want multiple components displayed then you need to use a different layout maanger or add the components to different areas of the BorderLayout.

Comment: It will be necessary to paint all parts of the custom rendering inside one panel.  In this case you might have a `Label` class that knows how and where to draw the string.  The custom component would have a collection of `Label` instances and paint them all when requested.  Very much agree with the point by @camickr about reading the tutorial.